# Add to database datetime in custom format

Tags: vb.net

I need to add the current date.time in database in format

> dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

This way without formatting works great

```
 Public Sub AddIt(Name As String)
    Try
        Dim addString As String = "Insert into table (Name, DateAdd) values ('" & Name & "', '" & Date.Now & "')"
        sqlcon.Open()
        SqlCom = New SqlCommand(addString, sqlcon)
        SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Tried with parameters to format

```
Public Sub Town(Name As String)
    Try
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim format As String = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
        Dim MyCommand As SqlCommand
        MyCommand = New SqlCommand("Insert into test (Name, DateAdd) values (@name, @test)", sqlcon)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", form2.txtName.Text)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", time.ToString(format))
        sqlcon.Open()
        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

It says connection was not closed. The connection state is open

Comment: open the connection before using it in `new SQL Command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question why you would need the date and time to be in the database in that format - it would be much easier to simply store the full Date object in the database as shown in the first code snippet, and then whenever you retrieve that data, convert it into the format you require using `DateTime.toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`

I have a feeling that your current problem is being caused by a previous exception - specifically, as you've not included any code in your exception handling, if the exception occurs as a result of a failed SQL statement, the connection will remain open - causing the next open call to fail.

You can rectify this by checking the connection state before attempting to re-open it - `SqlConnection` exposes a `ConnectionState` property that you can check to see if the connection is already open.

Comment: Yes didn't thought about it. Done on your way ;)   P.S Is there any way to get selected in datagridview row that has been last inserted/updated ???

Comment: Not that I know of. Worth a new question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Open the connection before initializing your `SQLcommand`

```
Public Sub Town(Name As String)
    Try
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim format As String = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
        sqlcon.Open()
        Dim MyCommand As SqlCommand
        MyCommand = New SqlCommand("Insert into test (Name, DateAdd) values (@name, @test)", sqlcon)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", form2.txtName.Text)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", time.ToString(format))
        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Still the same problem even with that.